# Android : How to get Content URIs

Tags: android, uri

I am new to android programming and wanted to know if there is a list of content URI available for reference

for eg. content://sms/inbox   - is content URI to access SMS inbox.

is there any such list which provides all the content URIs which can be used with the android system to get the data. I have searched the android SDK documentation and could not find all of them , for eg. the above SMS inbox one is not listed there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> for eg. content://sms/inbox - is content URI to access SMS inbox

No, that is not "content URI to access SMS inbox". That is a Uri pointing to a content provider used by an application that might (or might not) exist on any device and that [you have been told are not part of the Android SDK](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html).

> is there any such list which provides all the content URIs which can be used with the android system to get the data.

All of the documented and supported ones are in the `android.provider` package.

> for eg. the above SMS inbox one is not listed there.

That would be because it is not part of the operating system, any more than an Outlook API is part of Windows.

Comment: Quick question related to this. In your book "Beginning Android 2", Chapter 18, "Make an Intent", there is an intent with a uri starting with "geo:". Seen in the light of the blog post you are linking to, is this an example of the mentioned anti-pattern?

Comment: @rogerkk: No, because `geo:` is documented and supported. http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

Comment: @CommonsWare i am also using content://sms/inbox and content://sms/sent to access incoming and outgoing sms. But it not safe as u told it can be change anytime(You had added many  such comment  under diff quest). how can we do it alternatively to achieve same task? will you suggest me a solution?

Comment: @chrish: "how can we do it alternatively to achieve same task?" -- there is no alternative. You hope that, someday, Google adds an officially-supported `ContentProvider` for this data.